# the principle of the shared mode in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer

Tags: java, concurrency

In the progress of learning the code of the shared mode in AbstractQueuedSynchronizer(AQS), I have a question that i can not understand the following codes in setHeadAndPropagate:

```
if (propagate > 0 || h == null || h.waitStatus < 0) {
            Node s = node.next;
            if (s == null || s.isShared())
                doReleaseShared();
        }
```

"h" is the old head, why use old head to check?

Comment: Please can you add a little more context? It is unclear exactly what your question is as it stands.

Comment: I am not quiet understand the logic of the judgement in the  first if sentence. Why we should use this and use the old head? what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

If `state` is equal to 0 and no nodes are queued before, or if the previously queued node is 0 or `CANCELLED`, there is no need to wake up Successor.